# How to stake on devnet/testnet to test the TPU?

Tags: validator, devnet, testnet, testvalidator

I want to stake on devnet/testnet to test out the features of the solana-validator, specifically the TPU (Transaction Processing Unit) after I've made some changes to it before submitting a PR.

How do I do this? AFAIK you can only receive 2 SOL from an airdrop on testnet/devnet every few hours, that is not enough to stake & become the block leader more often than not.

There are no instructions regarding doing such thing on the official solana docs, hence I ask here.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Rather than relying on leader slots from a real network to test your changes, I would see if it's possible to test changes locally. The TPU works even on a `solana-test-validator`, so you can spam transactions at it to see how your change behaves. Getting leader slots on devnet or testnet will be very complicated, as you've seen